# Qual significado em usar arquivo robots em páginas no Github?

Tags: google, github, robots.txt

De acordo com essa [resposta do Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784322/stopping-index-of-github-pages) é possível usar o robots.txt para **evitar** que máquinas de busca indexem as páginas que o *webmaster* não deseja.

> Como isso é possível?
>
> > através de um `Custom Domain` ou domínio customizado.

Porém, se o objetivo do *robots* é delimitar uma área privada no site(por exemplo), qual é o sentido em tentar "esconder"(com o *robots*) algum conteúdo? se tudo pode ser visto livremente na plataforma do Github?

Para que o conteúdo fique efetivamente oculto ou escondido, então seria necessário pagar para a plataforma do Github e ter acesso ao recurso de repositórios privados?

Comment: Jonathas recomendo que leia as tags antes de adicionar na sua pergunta, a pergunta não tem relação com "Git" e a tag "Busca" é sobre algorítimos.

Comment: De fato, peço desculpas pelo ocorrido, irei prestar mais atenção, agradeço pelo aviso. Você consegue visualizar alguma outra tag que se encaixe na pergunta? eu tento colocar o máximo de tags possíveis para ganhar visibilidade, por isso acabo cometendo esses erros.

Comment: Os bots vão indexar os "sources" pelo github.com, só não vão indexar pelo github-pages, ou seja se esta usando o github-pages para um site proprio você vai bloquear alguns bots. Agora pro github.com o que vai indexar é como arquivos e "sources", não sei bem como explicar bem, mas essa é a diferença básica.